# Match all requests except public root for IE6 useragent using Apache Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, internet-explorer-6

I have a rule for my localhost (just my local WAMP server) that rewrites just localhost/ to index.php and all other requests to rewrite.php. I was able to achieve that using the following...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
```

I'm trying to make the opposite rule that matches all requests *except* `^$`, so `!^$` however that does not work. Essentially I want to make an exception for IE6 for some older stuff for just-in-case scenarios though for my modern projects moving forward have a universal upgrade page.

Here is one example I've tried that looks like it would work though doesn't.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\ ([56])\.
RewriteRule !^$ upgradedamnit\.php [L]
```

Some clarifications...

1. I'm very strict about not using user agents though to be frank if you're spoofing your browser to pose as IE6 and expect things to work well I've got some bad news for you.
2. This is just for my local environment, not my live environment though I always test locally before I commit something to a live environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\ [56]\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ upgradedamnit.php? [L]
```

The last 2 lines must be the very lines after `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer though unfortunately localhost/ (tested IE8) or 192.168.x.y/ (IE6 in VirtualBox connecting via IP) bring up the upgrade page instead of the root projects page. I tested this code absent without any other Apache code as well as emptying IE's cache and still no dice.

Comment: @John Do you mean even for I.E 8 its getting redirected to the upgrade page?

Comment: All I did was change [56] to [5678] to test IE8 as well. So http:// localhost / incorrectly gets the upgrade page, I need THAT to be the exception where the upgrade page is not displayed so I can test projects that DO support IE6 by accessing localhost/ (I'll worry about other exceptions for those directories).

Comment: @John you cannot test whether projects support a certain browser using `.htaccess`. I suggest you to use detection of browser capabilities.